# What does the double dash ( - - ) do in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have some formulas with `--` in them in Excel, and experiments confirm that `=--1` is indeed a valid formula that evaluates to 1. However, Googling doesn't return anything. What does `--` do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A minus sign changes a positive to a negative in standard excel formulas.

Using two minus signs `--` changes TRUE and FALSE to numbers:

```
=(1>2) =FALSE
=--(1>2) =0
=(2>1) =TRUE
=--(2>1) =1
```

More importantly, it's great to use in array formulas -

Take this table starting in cell `A1`

```
Primary Secondary   Count
red     blue        10
blue    red         20
yellow  red         30
red     blue        40
purple  green       50
blue    red         60
red     red         70
```

If you want to see how many you have of a specific combination, you can use a [sumproduct](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMPRODUCT-function-16753e75-9f68-4874-94ac-4d2145a2fd2e) like this -

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A2:A8="blue"),--(B2:B8="red"),C2:C8)
```

This will give you 80 by doing this to your table (literally multiplying ) -

```
blue    red    Count    Total
0   x   0   x   10   =   0
1   x   1   x   20   =   20
0   x   1   x   30   =   0
0   x   0   x   40   =   0
0   x   0   x   50   =   0
1   x   1   x   60   =   60
0   x   1   x   70   =   0
```

Essentially it's allowing you to use true/false conditions as multipliers in an array.
Whereas this formula

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A8="blue"),(B2:B8="red"),C2:C8)
```

will return 0. This would be useful for a time when [countifs](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842) wouldn't work with the summation.

If you're looking for information on google, the term you should search is **double dash**.

Comment: Yeah when I first ran into it I couldn't figure it out either. So I had to just mess around with `sumproducts` using it. Things get weight with `sumproduct` when you use `*` and `/` too..

Comment: I didn't read through all your answer, but actually  my doubledash is negated in a SUMPRODUCT. This answers the next question I was trying to figure out. Thanks!!

Comment: You can do this  `=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A8="blue")*(B2:B8="red"),C2:C8)` without invoking `--` at all.

Comment: Wouldn't `INT()` be more readable?  Or does that not work with arrays?

Comment: The answer is very clear, but as joehua said,  `SUMPRODUCT` is not a function where `--` is really needed. This [example](https://superuser.com/a/1333850/1007423) with `MMULT` is more relevant.

Answer (score 4):

`--` isn't an operator, `-` is the negation operator, but will also cast a boolean to an int. So `--TRUE` evaluates to 1 and `--FALSE` evaluates to 0.

[Source](http://www.k2e.com/tech-update/tips/143-using-two-minus-signs-in-excel).

Comment: The link is no longer available.